# Keeping a LinkedList always sorted

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I've been given a code as shown below for practice purpose, and my task is to modify it so that the linked list is always sorted. My main problem now is that I have no idea where to start or what methods are to be modified. Any hints are welcome.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

/
 * This is a copy of the LinkedList class, which has been modified to only
 * accept elements that can be compared.
 * 
 * Note that the elements accepted by this list must implement the Comparable
 * interface. This means that the elements can be compared as follows:
 *   
 * x.compareTo(y) == 0 means x == y
 * x.compareTo(y) < 0 means x < y
 * x.compareTo(y) > 0 means x > y
 * 
 * Your task is to modify this class so that the elements always are sorted.
 */
public class SortedLinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterable<T> {

/* Easy operations for a linked list

add(x): Searching for the place where the element x is to be added must
        take place in the calling routine. This must set previous to
        point to the node AFTER which the new element is to be inserted.
        curr is set to point to the new element.

remove(): The curr element is removed from the list. Searching for this 
          element must take place in the calling routine. This must set 
          curr to point to the element to be removed. After removal curr
          points to the element following the removed one. 

isEmpty(): checks for an empty list

endOfList(): checks whether curr has reached and passed the end of the list 

retrievecurr(): return the info part of the curr element.

reset(): resets the list so that curr points to the first element

succ(): an iterator, moves curr one step forward

Note that when a class implements the interface Iterable<T> then
it can be the target of the "foreach" statement. See IterationExample.java
 */

private Node start, curr, prev;

public SortedLinkedList() {

    curr = null;     // the curr position in the list
    start = null;    // the first element
    prev = null;     // the node before curr
}

public void add(T x) {

    if (start == null) {            // if start == null, insert a first element into an empty list
        Node newNode = new Node();  // create the new element, info and link are set to null.
        newNode.info = x;           // and assign the data given as parameter. The link is left as null            
        start = newNode;            // start is updated to point to the new element
        curr = start;               // curr is updated to point to the new first (and only) element

    } else if (prev == null) { // a new first element is inserterd into a non-empty list

        Node newNode = new Node();  // a new node is created ...
        newNode.info = x;           // and assigned the data given as parameter
        newNode.link = start;       // and linked before the old first element 
        start = newNode;            // start is updated to point to the new first element
        curr = newNode;             // curr is updated to point to the new first element

    } else { // a new element is inserted last (if prev.link == null) or between prev and curr

        Node newNode = new Node();  // create a new node 
        newNode.info = x;           // assign it the data given as parameter 
        newNode.link = prev.link;   // link it before curr ...
        prev.link = newNode;        // ... and after previous
        curr = newNode;             // update curr to point to newNode      
    }

} // add

public void remove() {              // removes the current node

    if (isEmpty() || endOfList()) { // no node to be removed 
        return;
    } 
    else {                          // curr points to the element to be removed 
        if (prev == null) {         // remove a first element: start is updated!
            start = start.link;     // "jump over" the first element (curr/start)
            curr = start;           // update curr to point to the new start
        } 
        else {                      // the element to be removed is in the middle of the list/last
            prev.link = curr.link;  // "jump over it!"
            curr = curr.link;       // curr is updated to the element after the removed one
        } 
    }
} // remove

public boolean isEmpty() { // checks if the list is empty
    return start == null;
}

public T retrieveCurr() { // return the curr element's data
    return curr.info;
}

public void reset() { // resets a list so that curr points to the first element

    curr = start;     // curr starts from the beginning of the list 
    prev = null;      // there is no previous element for curr
}

public boolean endOfList() { // has curr reached and passed the end of the list?

    return curr == null;
}

public void succ() { // moves curr to the next element

    curr = curr.link;       // curr is set to the next node
    if (prev == null) {     // previous must follow; if it was null to begin with ...
        prev = start;       // ... it must now point to start
    }
    else {
        prev = prev.link;   // otherwise it is just moved one step forward
    }
}

public Iterator<T> iterator(){ //Needed to implement the iterable interface
    return new ListIterator();
}

private class Node {

    T info;
    Node link;

    Node() {
        info = null;
        link = null;
    }
}

/*
 * An example iterator class to walk through the list from
 * the start to the end. Note the similarity with the methods
 * above. They implement similar functionality, but here it
 * is hidden behind a standard interface.
 * 
 * Note the class is private and the implementation of the iterator
 * is therefore not visible outside. 
 * 
 * See the java api documentation for more information on 
 * how iterators should behave.
 */
private class ListIterator implements Iterator<T>{

    private Node curr;

    public ListIterator(){
        curr=start;
    }

    public boolean hasNext(){
        return curr!=null;
    }

    public T next(){
        if(curr==null){
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        T value=curr.info;
        curr=curr.link;
        return value;
    }
    public void remove(){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: If you want list to be always sorted you must assure that you add every element in correct place. Think of it. You have method **add()** . Start from here.

Comment: First, ask you how to keep a list sorted at all times. Not in java code, but in general : if you are given a number of oranges, how do you organize yourself so that they are always sorted in increasing size?

Comment: Then, ask yourself if there is _really_ any practical application for such list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only big change in implementation which you have to make is to keep the list sorted as you insert elements.  Note that the reverse operation, namely removing elements, doesn't need to change, because you are simply throwing things away which would not change any order in the list.

The `add()` method below walks down the list until it finds the appropriate position.  Then, it splices in the new node and updates the `start`, `prev`, and `curr` pointers where applicable.

```
public void add(T x) {
    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.info = x;

    // case: start is null; just assign start to the new node and return
    if (start == null) {
        start = newNode;
        curr = start;
        // prev is null, hence not formally assigned here
        return;
    }

    // case: new node to be inserted comes before the current start;
    //       in this case, point the new node to start, update pointers, and return
    if (x.compareTo(start.info) < 0) {
        newNode.link = start;
        start = newNode;
        curr = start;
        // again we leave prev undefined, as it is null
        return;
    }

    // otherwise walk down the list until reaching either the end of the list
    // or the first position whose element is greater than the node to be
    // inserted; then insert the node and update the pointers
    prev = start;
    curr = start;
    while (curr != null && x.compareTo(curr.info) >= 0) {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr.link;
    }

    // splice in the new node and update the curr pointer (prev already correct)
    newNode.link = prev.link;
    prev.link = newNode;
    curr = newNode;
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did this code work out of the box for you?  I was expecting to have to go back and forth a few times actually.

Comment: Pretty much, yes. I have a test suite inserting elements 5,1,-2,7,3 into the list, but when I get the sorted list, "5" seems to be missing from it (so the list I get is [-2,1,3,7]

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with my code which would cause this.  If you can't resolve it on your own, comment here again and you can email the code to me.

Comment: I've narrowed it down to being something wrong when you add the number 7 anytime after number 5 (the list comes out correct [-2,1,3,5,7] if "7" is inserted before "5" into the list), but I can't really figure out where the code fails in that case.

Comment: @UserOrNotAnUser I just made a slight correction to the logic for adding a new node in the case where the new node should be placed at the very _end_ of the list.  I changed `curr.link != null` to `curr != null` and I think this should work now.

Comment: I actually tried that earlier, it throws a NullPointerException

Comment: @UserOrNotAnUser I switched the order of the `while` conditions so that `curr != null` is being checked first.  This should resolve the null pointer exception you were seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Well the key to ensure its order is through your `add()` method.

To sort in ascending order:

1) Read current node's value.

2) Iterate through the nodes till you encounter a node with value >= with current.

3) Insert node at that position.

The above can be applied with binary search to get position for insertion.
To sort in descending order, just ensure current node's value is < target node's value.

Comment: Binary search would be irrelevant for linked list, no?

Comment: Binary search can be useful when comparisons take a long time.